# Are the first letter of tag wiki excerpts supposed to be capitalized or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been running through the tag wikis giving excerpts to popular tags lately, and I've noticed that out of the ones that have already been filled in, almost all of the tag excerpts have a lowercase first letter, while I've been capitalizing them.

Which convention do we want to follow in regards to that? Should tag wiki excerpts be capitalized in sentence case or not?

Answer (score 1):

I hovered over the "discussion" tag on this meta question, which was created by SE staff. It begins with a capital letter. I know they're excerpts, but they're also complete sentences, so a capital letter makes sense.

Comment: Actually, a bunch of them that we've been making aren't complete sentences, including the ones I've been making. However, I'm still capitalizing them.